# How to write proper repeat signs for ABABBCB form?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, musical-forms, lead-sheets, repeats

I'm trying to write down the melody of a song.  It's in ABABBCB form, with a Coda.  It also has a pickup measure.  This is what I came up with.  Is this correct?  In the 2nd volta (ending), should it be double bar line (as shown) or the repeat sign (same as in 1st volta)?  Is the "D.S. sign-symbol" without "al Coda" clear enough that one goes back to the sign and then the 3rd volta?

[image: Example of form as score]

To clarify, the intended play order is: pickup, A, B, 1st-ending, A, B, 2nd-ending, B, C, B, Coda.

Comment: If it's only for you to see then it doesn't matter, but I wouldn't use _any_ repeats in such a short passage. Just write it out!

Comment: Although I'm showing only 1 to 2 bars per section here, in reality each section has 4 to 8 bars.

Comment: Even so, if other musicians are going to be playing it I would advise you to avoid nested repeat-signs. Rehearsals can be a nightmare. Instead of saying,  "Let's go from the fifth bar of E" you end up saying, "The second time of E on the dal segno but after the first repeat." Or "Let's do the six bars before the coda but not the time we actually GO to the coda." Where have you ever _seen_ music written your way?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - The Boosey & Hawkes publication of Edward Elgar's Pomp and Circumstance March No. 2 in A Minor combines both repeat signs and dal segno al coda, so "Let's do the six bars before the coda but not the time we actually GO to the coda" actually makes sense as a direction. Luckily, there are explicit instructions on the score to *skip* the repeat after the dal segno instruction has been reached.

Comment: @Dekkadeci: It's a mess, that score! In fact it's a good example of the confusion I was warning about. If you try to follow it while listening to the piece you get lost. The first repeat - with its 1st time and 2nd time bars before B - is written correctly. There should just be a ||: (start-repeat sign) before the 3rd bar of E. Delete the segno sign after the second bar. Delete the "D.C. al Coda" at the 18th bar of J and delete the segno sign above it at the same place(!), but keep that bar's :|| (end-repeat sign).
Also in the 18th bar, keep the 1st and 2nd time lines...

Comment: ... Delete the word CODA from the last page: it isn't needed. It would make sense to move figure "E" to two bars later, where the new ||: is. Btw, there's a subtle piece of writing for the tuba in the bar before the "CODA": only holding for a crotchet, when everyone else has a minim. It produces a more interesting fade than in the 2nd bar of E, where he forgot to do it!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - Ah right, I'd listened to Pomp and Circumstance March No. 2 in A Minor so many times - and even transcribed it for solo piano - that it turns out that I misspoke about some of its directions. However, from all those times I've listened to various versions of that march, there should **not** be any repeat signs in the vicinity of E, the last set of voltas and repeat signs (and last segno) should be ditched, there should be a "To coda" where the start of that old last first ending is, and the "D.C. al segno" instruction should be a "D.S. al coda" instruction...

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - ...but the word "CODA" should be kept (or replaced by a coda sign). With those in, that first segno after Bar 2 **must** be kept.

Comment: @Dekkadeci: I was listening to [this version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrCBIwGkN8Q) by the English Symphony Orchestra under William Boughton.  I guess the only reason others versions exist is that the markings are so muddled. I'm sure it'd be _possible_ to make a version with segnos and capos, but - at least for the ESO version - they're unnecessary. It's a good piece, eh? I do like his horn writing. I'll listen to a some other versions at some point and compare them. I'd like to hear yours too.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - You asked for my version/piano transcription of Pomp and Circumstance March No. 2 in A Minor, and I've delivered: https://musescore.com/user/9996931/scores/5310430. It's mostly based on the Royal Scottish National Orchestra interpretation, though I listened to a few others and most of them match the RSNO one structurally. I'd previously left a comment on the very ESO interpretation video you gave a link to on how that one cut off too much of the march (compared to other interpretations).

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - FWIW, the Schmid piano transcription (which I could not find online at the time I made my transcription) also replaces the extremely confusing "D.C. al segno" instruction with a "D.S. al coda" instruction, although it bizarrely leaves both segnos there. It similarly ditches the last repeat sign but confusingly leaves both of the last 2 voltas there.

Comment: @Dekkadeci: [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126233/the-auditorium)?

Answer (score 4):

What you've written correctly represents your intended order. It's the most efficient way to write it if the goal is to save paper, but it's not the most clear to follow as a performer. A more conventional way to write it would be

A, B, 1st ending
A, B, 2nd ending
B C B Coda

[image: Illustration of conventional score organization]

You could add a little efficiency by writing

A, B, 1st ending
A, B, 2nd ending
B, 1st ending = C
B, 2nd ending = Coda

[image: Illustration of variation with efficiency gain]

Comment: Thanks for the two other ways of writing.  Yes, I was trying to minimize space; i.e. write down as few notes as possible, so that the whole song could fit on 1 page.  But as you have pointed out, it might not be clear to the performer.  I suppose it's matter of taste and compromise between the 2 extreme: most compact vs everything written out.  I'm glad I got the compact way correctly, but I'm now leaning towards to use your first version instead.

Comment: @Purple Glad it was helpful. FWIW, bands I played with would sometimes just notate several sections separately and then write down a roadmap. So a chart might look like music labeled "Intro" "Verse" "Chorus" (or "A" "B" "C"), and then there would be a section of text like "Intro 2x / Verse / Chorus / Intro / Chorus /  Middle part / Verse / Ending".